# Pyinstaller pythonfile.py Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert my .py file to an exe file. I've done it in the past but for some reason it isn't working anymore. I am using Python 2.7 and have other versions installed as well but my application won't work without 2.7. If I do python activityKivy.py it runs perfectly. I also tried with py2exe but was unsuccessful, it gave me too many dll warnings and would crash each time I open it. I prefer to stick with pyinstaller because thats what always worked for me. Some help would greatly be appreciates!

error screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update: I wasn't able to figure out exactly what the problem was but I was playing around with my environment variables and changing my pip names to pip2 pip3 and thats when this problem started happening and even when I reverted all my changes it still showed me this.I was able to fix it by simply uninstalling pyinstaller and redownloading it.